# Negative number error while checking proper input of unsigned long long

Tags: c, scanf, unsigned-long-long-int

I need to check, if input is properly given, like throw out some wrong inputs, like 'b', -2, etc. Heres my simple code, how to check it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long bigNumber;
    if(scanf("%llu", &bigNumber) == 0)
        printf("Input error!");
    else
        printf("%llu\n", bigNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

However when I input

```
-2
```

I got this output:

```
18446744073709551614
```

which is wrong, because -2 is not an unsigned long long.

When I tried to change the input condition on

```
if((scanf("%llu", &bigNumber) == 0) || (bigNumber < 0))
```

suprisingly, I got a compilation error:

```
ex.c:6:52: error: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
      [-Werror,-Wtautological-compare]
        if((scanf("%llu", &bigNumber) == 0) || (bigNumber < 0))
                                                ~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~
1 error generated.
```

So, how do I check my Big Number properly, if it has to be a whole number between 0 - 10^19?

Comment: Input as string (like `fgets`) then Check if it starts with `-` then `sscanf` or `strtoull`

Answer (score 0):

In the C99 standard the input value minus sign is optional, so if a minus sign is read, no errors will arise and the result will be the two's complement of a negative number, likely a very large value. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string))

You must either read in a signed number and check against `x < 0`, or cast the read unsigned value to signed before comparison.